# jenkins cannot read from remote repository

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

this is my pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
      stage('MVD python') {
          steps {
              git url: 'ssh://git@git.rocketsoftware.com:7999/lg6/mvdzos.git',
                  credentialsId: 'edawes',
                  branch: 'master'

              sh 'ls -l'
           }
      }
    }
}
```

simply trying to test if i can get access to the repo however I am getting the error

Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@git.rocketsoftware.com:7999/lg6/mvdzos.git

> git --version # timeout=10
>   git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@git.rocketsoftware.com:7999/lg6/mvdzos.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@git.rocketsoftware.com:7999/lg6/mvdzos.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: Host key verification failed.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

beyond the obvious access rights issue which I am pretty sure I have, what else could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the git command that causes to error on the Jenkins server as the Jenkins user.

```
git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@git.rocketsoftware.com:7999/lg6/mvdzos.git
```

You might get an SSH warning which you have to confirm manually.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the error:

`stderr: Host key verification failed`

is what's going on here - your Jenkins can't confirm that `git.rocketsoftware.com:7999` is legitimate, so it's bailing on the whole procedure.

Does Jenkins have a known_hosts file you can add that server to?

Answer (score 0):

On **all Jenkins nodes** where this would be probably running (that is all including the master if it has some executors configured) you'll need to make sure to have a working **ssh configuration**.

In particular it tells you that there's some issue with the host key verification. Logon to that machine and check whether. While playing around on that machine you may use `ssh git@git.rocketsoftware.com:7999` to see whether you fixed the issue.

- Any possible existing host key probably needs an update
- Strict host key checking is enabled (in `~/.ssh/config`) but there's no host key given in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`